# Angular: Cannot change value of bound (=) variable in directive from transcluded child of second directive with shared scope

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, two-way-binding

This is a complex question so I apologize for the complicated-sounding title.

Basically I have this situation:

I have a directive with

```
scope: false,
transclude: true
```

(I'll call this Directive1) Directive1's template references a second directive (Directive2) with an isolated scope into which I pass a variable that is two-way-bound using the '='. e.g.

```
pageTitle: '='
```

The variable I'm binding to that from Directive1 is on Directive1's $scope.

```
page-title="pageTitle"
```

OK, now, I have a controller (we'll call Controller1) that is embedded in the transcluded content from Directive1 that needs to change the value of pageTitle. Since the Directive1 has a shared scope I can easily read the value of $scope.pageTitle from within Controller1, however, when I attempt to change the value, it is not propagated down through the two-way binding of Directive2. This seems like something that should be possible, but I cannot figure out how.

However, if I create a new function in Directive1 like this:

```
$scope.changePageTitle(newTitle){
    $scope.pageTitle = newTitle;
}
```

And call that function from within Directive2:

```
$scope.changePageTitle('Whatever I Want');
```

It *does* successfully change the value of the variable in Directive1 and Directive2.

Here is a jsfiddle with an example of the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/aou5za7z/3/

Notice if you type a value in the first input box it only affects the Controller1 Value, however you can change the values in Directive1 and Directive2 by typing a value in the second input and hitting "Change Title"

Do I need to use the method workaround, or should there be a way to change the value in Directive2 from within Controller1 via the shared scope Directive1 and Controller1 both share?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Actually, may have just found the answer to my question. I don't use transclude: true pretty much ever and didn't realize that it messes with scopes. It looks like I may not have a shared scope after all. Still leaving this open in case there's a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is happening because you can't have a shared scope with a transcluded directive, instead you get an inherited scope.